# Error in build in Visual Studio 2008 (C# project)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

today i get this error

> The specified path, file name, or both
>   are too long. The fully qualified file
>   name must be less than 260 characters,
>   and the directory name must be less
>   than 248 characters.

note that I've been working on the same solution and in the same directory since 1 month and i didn't get this error.
any idea ?

Comment: In what context do you get this error - from an app at runtime, popup from the IDE, during a build?

Comment: @Steve, there's `build` right there in the question title ;)

Comment: @Frédéric, thanks - so the build log should be added to the question text.

Comment: I delete the bin folder from the project solution and after the build I get this error and the folder bin and the folder debug is created with some files but the .exe file is not created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Problem is solved when I delete unused references in the solution 
I don't know what is the issue but the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

You most likely added one more folder to your solution somewhere inside an existing folder.  A full path is all the characters that you need to specify the location of a file.  All files in a solutions must have a short enough path.
So if you had
c:'..many folders..\Project\file
this was still ok but when you added
c:'..many folders..\Project\newfolder\file
you broke the camel's back

Comment: I know the definition of the full path and I didn't touch the solution path or the solution name and i check the length and the length is less than 146 character

Comment: i am not saying that you changed the solution path.  I am saying that you added a file to the solution that exceeded the path length